# tinymce converts string to html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

The problem  of tinymce is that converting my string (Greek Language) to html tags

For examble:
The word - Ανακοίνωση

Is changed in database to

```
&Alpha; &nu; &alpha; &kappa; &omicron; ί&nu; &omega; &sigma; &eta;
```

with semi-column between them.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your TinyMCE Initialisation, you can add an option [`entity_encoding`](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:entity_encoding):

```
tinyMCE.init({
  ...
  entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

> **`raw`** All characters will be stored in non-entity form except these XML default entities: `&amp; &lt; &gt; &quot;`

From the [documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:entity_encoding):

[image: doc]